# Positive semi-definiteness of the Jacobian of the partial derivatives of distinct convex functions

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, monotone-functions, jacobian, hessian-matrix

Let  $f_i: \mathbb{R}^{Nn} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be *convex* and *twice continously differentiable* functions for every $i=1...N$. Consider the function $F: \mathbb{R}^{Nn} \times \mathbb{R}^{Nn}$ defined as follows $$F(x_1,...,x_N)=\begin{bmatrix}\nabla_{x_1}f_1(x_1,...,x_N)\\\nabla_{x_2}f_2(x_1,...,x_N)\\...\\\nabla_{x_N}f_N(x_1,...,x_N)\end{bmatrix}\,,$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for every $i=1...N$. Is the Jacobian of $F$, $JF \in \mathbb{R}^{Nn \times Nn}$, always positive semi-definite for any choice of functions $f_i$?  If not, could you provide a counter-example?

Comment: What is $N_n$? ${}$

Comment: It's $Nn$, not $N_n$. I mean the standard product of $N$ and $n$. For simplicity, we could also pose $n=1$, I think the problem would remain the same.

Comment: Removed a few typos.

Comment: The Jacobian is not necessarily symmetric, which is a requirement for positive semi-definiteness.